# How do you properly access a .set assembly variable from C?

Tags: c, assembly, gnu-assembler

I have a variable in an assembly file that I set using

```
.set CODE_SELECTOR 0x08
.global CODE_SELECTOR
```

I then have a C file with CODE_SELECTOR declared as extern and I'm trying to simply access the value of it which should be 0x08.
When I actually call a C function with CODE_SELECTOR as an argument, C is treating it as if I want the contents at memory location CODE_SELECTOR and I end up with the following assembly code

```
mov    0x8,%eax
sub    $0xc,%esp
push   %eax
call   0x284
```

If I call the same function with an explicit number like 0x08 instead, I end up with the expected code

```
sub    $0xc,%esp
push   $0x8
call   0x284
```

So how should I go about properly accessing the "value" of CODE_SELECTOR and not the contents at CODE_SELECTOR? I think it might have something to do with assembly symbol types but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I'd change the _C_ code to pass CODE_SELECTOR to the assembly function as a parameter. And in the _C_ code just use `#define CODE_SELECTOR 0x08` . This avoids having to have a symbol in assembly. What you are doing is possible, but I'm trying to steer you in another direction.

Comment: Well it's a normal C function, not an assembly function. And while I could define CODE_SELECTOR, that just means if I ever want to change it, I have to do it at two spots.

Comment: If you pass CODE_SELECTOR as a parameter to an assembly function it only has to be defined on the _C_ side.

Comment: I'll ask you this. Are you trying to create an assembly function that does `lgdt` and then sets the segment (Code and Data) selectors?

Comment: You can define CODE_SELECTOR as a C macro in one file and include it in both your C and assembly code. Use `gcc -c foo.S` to assemble the assembly file (renaming it so it has capital S extension) so that it gets run through the C preprocessor. Otherwise you'll need to to take the address of CODE_SELECTOR to get the value you want, since C thinks all external symbols are addresses.

Comment: Ah, you showed me the issue Ross Ridge. I wasn't aware that extern variables in C are addresses. This post explains it more:https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2007-07/msg00154.html

Comment: @user3211355 That's because you can *write* to variables whereas you can't change the values of symbols. So the symbol only points to the memory location containing the variable we want to read.